# Trying to Add more than 2 variables in Logic App Cosmos DB

Tags: addition, azure-logic-apps

Requirement in Logic App : Need to add 4 variables into a single variable.

I am using the expression Add(Variable1, variable2, variable3, variable4)

But it throws the below error.
[image: Error]

Is there any other way to add 4 variables(int).

[image: Expression Add]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compound them, i.e. use this concept ...

```
add(add(add(variables('Number 1'), variables('Number 2')), variables('Number 3')), variables('Number 4'))
```

This test flow ...

[image: Flow]

... gives me this result when I add them using that compound approach ...

[image: Result]

However, if the amount of numbers you're adding is dynamic, you may need to loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. you saved my time. That was so quick and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since Add()'s synatx is Add(summand1,summand2), you can do something like below

```
Add(variables('Variable1'),Add(variables('Variable2'),Add(variables('Variable3'),variables('Variable4'))))
```

Here is my logic app

[image]

**RESULT:**

[image]